# Oracle PL/SQL function to return rows or rowids

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, pipelined-function

I want to write a function that returns table records that I can show in my app's grid. My app shall be oblivious to the table's structure. I want it to be still working when someone adds columns to the table or removes them.

In my app it shall look something like this:

```
myQuery = "select * from table(myfunction)";
...
```

The function should hence be something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction RETURN TABLE OF mytable%ROWTYPE AS ...
```

But `RETURN TABLE OF mytable%ROWTYPE` is not allowed. One has to create an SQL type.

But `CREATE TYPE table_of_mytable_rows IS TABLE OF mytable%ROWTYPE` is not allowed either.

So, is there a way to achieve exactly what I want?

As an alternative I thought of working with IDs. This would make my app's code look something like this:

```
myQuery = "select * from mytable where rowid in (select * from table(myfunction))";
...
```

And the function would then be

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction RETURN TABLE OF UROWID AS ...
```

But again, `RETURN TABLE OF UROWID` is not allowed. Neither is creating the SQL table type with `CREATE TYPE table_of_rowids IS TABLE OF UROWID`.

I know I could create an object type resembling the table's primary key columns and then create a table type on this object. Then my app would have to know the table's primary key in order to

```
myQuery = "select * from mytable where (key1, key2) in (select key1, key2 from table(myfunction))";
...
```

I would much prefer my function to return table rows or rowids. Is this possible?

I'm currently still working on Oracle 11.2, but I would also be interested in solutions for newer versions.

Comment: Why do you want a function at all - why not just query the table directly? Or, if you're trying to hide it logic used in the function to determine which rows are returned, have the function return a ref cursor opened for your underlying query (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252457/266304) perhaps)?

Comment: @Alex Poole: The real scenario is much more complicated of course :-) This is about reporting batch logs to a user, but which logs are currently interesting to a user depends on who this user is and what their role in the company is. There is quite some dynamic SQL inside the function. What would I gain from returning a ref cursor? Would my app (let it be C#) be able to access it?

Comment: If you call the function as a statement rather than a query, I don't see why not; I've linked to a Java example, but I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4126886/266304) might be what you're looking for? Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32953374/266304)? (I don't use C# so can't be too sure!)

Comment: @Alex Poole: Wow, yes, I didn't even think I would be able to access a ref cursor from outside of PL/SQL, but you are right, there is an `OracleRefCursor` in `OracleManagedDataAccess`, which is the .NET library I am using. Thank you very much, Alex, I will use a ref cursor.

Comment: Yes.. Almost all  popular high-level languages with Oracle db APIs would generally have an interface to deal with ref cursors.